# How can you pass in an argument list as a vector to a protocol declaration in Clojure?

Tags: parameters, clojure, protocols

When I enter this on the REPL:

```
> (defprotocol protocolname (methodname [a b]))
```

This works.

```
protocolname
```

Similarly when I enter this on the REPL:

```
> (defprotocol protocolname (methodname ['a 'b]))
```

It works.

```
protocolname
```

But when I enter this on the REPL:

```
> (let [arg-vec ['a 'b]]
    (defprotocol protocolname (methodname arg-vec)))
```

It fails with this error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration missing,
```

My question is: <s>**Why does this Clojure protocol declaration fail unexpectedly with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration missing`?**</s>

---

Update - thanks to @Mars - we have some additional information:

The macroexpansion of the line

```
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(defprotocol protocolname (methodname [a b]))))
```

contains this line:

```
:sigs
 '{:methodname {:doc nil, :arglists ([a b]), :name methodname}}
```

The macroexpansion of the line:

```
(let [arg-vec ['a 'b]]
   (pprint (macroexpand-1
             '(defprotocol protocolname (methodname arg-vec)))))
```

Has the line:

```
'{:methodname {:doc arg-vec, :arglists nil, :name methodname}}
```

This tells us that when you pass in a vector var to a `defprotocol` declaration - the var is assigned to the `:doc` and not the `:arglist`. (But when you declare the vector inside the `dedprotocol` call, then it assigns the vector to the `:arglist`.

So I'm going to update the question.

The question is now: **How can you pass in an argument list as a vector to a protocol declaration in Clojure?**

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will be able to give a deeper answer, but the following neverless seems worth offering as an answer:

If you execute

```
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(defprotocol protocolname (methodname ['a 'b]))))
```

and

```
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(defprotocol protocolname (methodname [a b]))))
```

and then compare their output to the output of

```
(let [arg-vec ['a 'b]]
   (pprint (macroexpand-1
             '(defprotocol protocolname (methodname arg-vec)))))
```

you'll see that there's a significant difference in how the macro `defprotocol` is expanded.  (I'm not going to reproduce the expansions here, since the first two are quite long.)

The macroexpansion process looks at the actual, pre-evaluation arguments.  A quick glance at the expansions shows that when the form after `methodname` is a sequence, each of the sequence's elements is processed separately, whereas when the form is `arg-vec`, it is `arg-vec` alone, unevaluated, that is processed by the expansion process.

Answer (score 0):

There is working solution but it's not nice (because of `eval` use):

```
(defmacro defprotocol-with-args [name methodname args-coll]
  `(defprotocol ~name (~methodname [~@(eval args-coll)])))
```

You can change `[~@(eval args-coll)]` to `~(eval args-coll)` but then it will work only for vectors (code above works with any flat sequence of symbols).

Tests:

```
(defprotocol-with-args protocolname methodname '[a b]) ; => protocolname
(def args '[a b]) ; => #'user/args
(defprotocol-with-args protocolname methodname args) ; => protocolname
(macroexpand-1 `(defprotocol-with-args protocolname methodname args)) ; => (clojure.core/defprotocol user/protocolname (user/methodname [a b]))
(macroexpand-1 `(defprotocol-with-args protocolname methodname '[a b])) ; => (clojure.core/defprotocol user/protocolname (user/methodname [user/a user/b]))
```

**Note** This is tested in REPL only. It's hard to predict how this approach will behave in general case.